# ApexMocks and UoW implementing IDoWork interface

Tags: apex, fflib, apexmock

I have extended the main functionality of the fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork to enable `upserts` considering External Ids. Basically, I have created a new class implementing the fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.IDoWork interface to do the job.

```
public class UnitOfWorkUpsertExtension implements fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.IDoWork {
public Database.UpsertResult[] results {get; private set;}

private Map<Schema.SObjectField, List<SObject>> m_records;

public UnitOfWorkUpsertExtension() {
    m_records = new Map<Schema.SObjectField, List<SObject>>();
}

public void registerUpsert(SObject record, Schema.SObjectField externalId) {

    if(m_records.containsKey(externalId)){
        m_records.get(externalId).add(record);
    }else{
        m_records.put(externalId,new List<SObject>{record});
    }
}

public void doWork() {

    for(Schema.SObjectField key : m_records.keySet()){
        Database.upsert(m_records.get(key), key,false);
    }

}
```

}

From a functionality point of view, everything is working as expected, however, I am not able to identify how can I test this new method in the same way with the ones provided by default, I mean, is there any option to use the ***verify*** method without implementing all the logic behind it? I would like to do something like this, where X is the record.

```
((fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(unitOfWorkMock)).registerUpdate(X);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is actually limpid, your business logic is unpure(depends on the return of a dml statement)

Your worker is the thing you want to mock, not the UoW. For that you need to tinker a bit with your domain:

- declare your IDoWork in the class level of your domain class
- use polymorphism to manually inject the mock instance during your test

It took me a bit of time to go around this issue as well, do not beat yourself, it's abstract and the framework imposes arbitrary stuffs on top of the abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

Two places to unit test:

- Use standard `mocks.verify` to unit test that you registered an `IdoWorker`

  ```
  ((fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.verify(unitOfWorkMock))
          .registerWork((UnitOfWorkUpsertExtension)fflib_Match.anyObject());
  ```
- Have your `doWork()` method call either a domain or service (I'd use service) layer to do the actual upsert. Then you can verify that the service method was actually called with the right arguments

  ```
  public void doWork() {
    MyService.doUpsert(m_records);
  }
  ```

  with test verify

  ```
  ((IMyService) mocks.verify(myServiceMock))
          .doUpsert((Map<Schema.SObjectField, List<SObject>>)fflib_Match.anyObject());
  ```

You can of course use more sophisticated matchers to verify the exact Map is being passed to the service class method